# Blender compositor canvas

Tags: compositing-nodes

This time my question is quite straight forward. How can I set up a canvas in Blender compositor. I explain better. I have an image that's too big and need to be resized. The edges of the image are all the same color and I wish to resize it on an other monocrome image. Is it possible to create using the nodes a black [or white or any other color] filled image defining also the sizes?

Thank you for your answer
Have a nice day!

Comment: You may use a **Scale** node (Add-->Distort-->Scale).

Answer (score 1):

Go into the compositor, and add an *Add* > *Distort* > *Scale* node.